# I have multiple in-game Louis Letrush

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am just recovering from a GPU crash. I started playing again. And I found multiples of Louis Letrush *again*. I replaced my graphics card. And imported my last important save before my GPU died.

[image: Multiple Louis Letrush]

Patch 1.5.

Is my game bugged?

Comment: You should share some with that other person then, stop hogging all the Louises! ;)

Comment: >UESP has no mention of it ORLY http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Louis_Letrush

Comment: Cant answer as such, just to say it happend to me after I was given a thieves guild quest to steal from the stables in one of the large towns (Forget which one). Looks like the same place as your screenie ! The only difference is ... One of my duplicates is stuck in the ground, up to his waist :)

Comment: Hmmmmm I wonder if you'd get multiple bounties for killing the "same" person over and over.... And why are they all talking

Comment: I had the same thing on my ps3. I killed all but one of them, paid my bounty and all seems fine now. But mine was slightly different as I had seven of em standin' there and they caused lag issues.

Comment: @kotekzot you're wrong that the usep didn't say: `Louis Letrush is associated with a very common glitch in which he becomes duplicated multiple times and/or becomes embedded in the ground just outside Whiterun.`

Comment: @Jim first of all, that's what I was saying. Second, that was over 3 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Louis_Letrush#Louis_Letrush_Clone_Glitch :

> **Louis Letrush Clone Glitch**
>
> The glitch produces multiple copies of Louis Letrush. The cause is currently unknown. This primarily occurs outside of Whiterun Stables.
>
> **Semi-Confirmed Details**
>
> - Glitch seems to depend on the completion of Letrush's related quest 'Promises to Keep'.
> - Initial glitch cause is unknown.
> - However  further copies of Letrush cloned upon the use of carriages.
> - It appears impossible to kill Letrush (and any of his clones), perhaps    due to his essential status.

---

(*I am assuming you have the PC version, since you mentioned replacing your graphics card and you've posted a PC screenshot.*)

Install the **[Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=19)** ([Bethesda forums thread](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1364672-relz-unofficial-skyrim-patch-thread-5/)) to fix it (and prevent more Louis Letrush clones from spawning). One of its fixes is:

> Louis Letrush should no longer duplicate at the Whiterun Stables fast-travel marker or attack the player for no apparent reason.

If it doesn't fix it or you'd rather not install it, you could also 'remove' Louis Letrush from the game, but it's better to do this after you've already finished the [quest related to Louis Letrush (*Promises to Keep*)](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Promises_to_Keep), to avoid bugs related to that quest.

Make a save game first, and then in the game, open up the [console](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) by pressing <kbd>~</kbd>, then click on one of Letrush's clones ([RefIDs](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs) of the clones start with 'FF', original does not start with 'FF'), type `disable` and then `markfordelete`. This will 'remove' the Louis clones from the game. I'd do this for each clone, and then try to keep the original Louis. You may `disable` and `markfordelete` the original Louis if you want to, too.

Answer (score 1):

From [this source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Whiterun_(City)), it says: "Upon entering the city at whiterun stables, after completing the quest 'Promises To Keep', upto 3 or 4 Louis Letrush's can spawn there" As far as I no there is no solution but I dont think this is too major of a bug so you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, on the PS3. I think I got up to 7-10 Louis's total. 
However, when I downloaded Hearthfire and Dawnguard, the next time I went to the stables, there were ZERO Louis Letrush's. I don't know if it was the DLC that fixes it or a patch I don't know about, but the problem's fixed.